# How to reinstall an app without losing NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have an iOS game that saves game progress using NSUserDefaults. After the last update a user had a problem, the app was not working anymore on this device. The app doesn't have any problem, but for some reason an error occurred while downloading the app, not quite sure what happened.

The point is, the app must be deleted and reinstalled. Can this be done without erasing NSUserDefaults?

I tried syncing with iTunes here after deleting the app, even installing it again through iTunes but I was unable to restore the previous saved game on my test devices.

I guess the only way to reinstall the app is through an app update. When it comes out he will update and will not lose any data. Is this correct? Or is there any other way to do this?

I'm working to implement cloud syncing on the next update, so this problem should not be an issue again :). But right now, is there anything and I do to this user?

Comment: Is this the kind of thing "Game Center" was build for, or is Game Center only for publishing & sharing scores?

Comment: If your user is technically inclined, he could use something like Phone View to grab the contents of the Preferences directory and then restore it after reinstalling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store user-data correctly on iOS? Case with NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925228/how-to-store-user-data-correctly-on-ios-case-with-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 0):

Cloud sync would be the solution. If you using your iPhone only once the app is deleted every thing related to it is gone with no easy way to retrieve it.

Comment: Yes I agree, but unfortunately the game doesn't have it yet... I guess there is nothing to do now, this user will lose his game. But I guess if he doesn't delete the app and wait for the next update the app will be reinstalled, and since he didn't delete the app his stats will not be lost.

Comment: @tomDev in that case, the app is not reinstalled but upgraded, and nothing of the data will be touched.

Comment: H2CO3, thanks, that's what I'm thinking. I will tell him to hang in there and wait for the next update.

Answer (score 0):

Or just store data that needs to be persistent in the keychain.

Answer (score 0):

Restoring the device from an iTunes Backupd probably reinstalls the app and also keeps the `NSUserDefaults`, assuming they are included in the backup.

However, this needs to be done by the user ...
Some syncing option is the better solution on the long way.